# Powershell add-content array output displaying System.Object[]

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array named $RolesFunArray. It contains one or more elements like this:

```
ZPP01 0  
ZPP02 1   
ZPP03 1
```

All arrays are system.string except for $RolesFunArray which is system.object.

I am trying to output this variable to a text file. It always shows the object type and not the string. I have tried -join, [string]$RolesFunArray and several other things and none of them work (no errors, just more System.Object[]).

Basically, I am reading a larger file line by line, grabbing some text, matching that text against another file and then picking text from the two files and writing them together to that $Line variable, which I then am outputting to a new line in a third file. I want tabs between the variables in the $Line output.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is what I am using to output.

```
$Line = $FirstWord[1] + ([char]0x0009) + $TstcSplit[6] + ([char]0x0009) + $RolesFunArray

add-content -Encoding ASCII -path "c:\sapdl\test\$File.log" -value "$Line'r"
```

Comment: It might be difficult to reproduce your issue here as you have variables we have to assume their state. `$FirstWord` is a string? If not that would be an issue. That would be my first question since it would determine how the object is saved. Also, if `$line` was typed earlier it would persist that way throughout the code. `$RolesFunArray` should just be a space delimited string if cast as such. What is `$FirstWord.GetType().Fullname`

Comment: Also if you are building a tab delimited file might as well crate you own objects and use `Export-CSV -delimiter "`t"`

Comment: $FirstWord.GetType().Fullname reports as being a string.

Comment: Then the type of `$line` should be string as well. Is that the case?

Comment: $RolesFunArray.GetType().Fullname reports as system.object

Comment: Does the string look like this then "D<tab>5<tab>System.Object[]"? `+ "$RolesFunArray"` should just work..... how does `$RolesFunArray`get populated..... Is this not a string array but an object array then? What is the type of `$RolesFunArray[1].GetType().Fullname`

Comment: $Line.GetType().Fullname is system.string

Comment: Yes, $Line is good except when it outputs the $RolesToString variable (which is an object). It shows ZP001    This is a description     system.object[]

Comment: While $RolesFunArray reports as system.object, each element reports as system.string

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to:

```
$RolesForFunArray | Export-Csv out.csv
```

There are number of other functions to let you use xml, json etc.
Otherwise you could simply try `"$RolesForFunArray"`

The output depends on type of object ofcourse, this works for `String[]` arrays. For other types you need to convert it via foreach loop item by item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to output the array as string into another variable ($Line) which then outputs to a file using that add-content line in the code I posted. Using quotes around the $RolesFunArray (still output system.object[]) did not work. I'll keep poking around as I am stuck!